# About SymmetricDS

Tags: synchronization, symmetricds

I’m trying to create an application for sync data in both directions from a central database server to several clients with individuals databases, there is not a constant connection among the parts. The idea is that the user with a simple flash drive with a portable application and a portable database can move from one place to another working on the field (generating records changes: additions, modifications and deletions) when he/she wishes to sync (hours or days), goes to the office and connects to the remote server and synchronizes the information, of course from the last time of the sync, there will be server changes that needs to be updated on the client and in some cases will be conflicts that need to be solved… The question is: Can I carry out this using SymmetricsDS? Could be the central database different from the clients (For instance: Central database Postgre and SQLite for clients).
Thanks,
Klueze.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes and yes

Symmetricds is made for this kind of jobs and it does allow different types of databases at the central node and clients. Even the client's databases can be heterogenous. You can have few clients implemented with SQLite and few others with mySql, for example.